# Equivilant of rails partials for angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Is there an equivilant of rails partials for angular js.

Ex: in rails I have my `application.html.erb` and I can do `<%= render 'layouts/_header` and it will render that header for every page.

Does angular have similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using ngInclude directive.

See the docs and example here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

You might also want to checkout angular-ui-router module. It allows you to do nested and parallel views. It is great, flexible, easy to use and well documented. 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router